# Firebase dynamic link custom params

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, dynamic, hyperlink

'm having trouble with the final steps implementing firebase to our unity app, any help would be really really appreciated

The problem involves receiving custom parameters when the app is opened by a dynamic link

The app opens fine, redirects to store etc if needed so that's ok but when I try to use the custom parameter it never holds the desired info but instead returns the fallback url to our website, I'm using the on link received function copied from dynamic link test app.

the outgoing link looks like this - "https://fbb.page.link/PL/?p=XXXXXXXXXX; where XXXXX is the param im looking for

```
 void Start() {
 DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;
 }

 void OnDynamicLink(object sender, EventArgs args) {
 var dynamicLinkEventArgs = args as ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs;
 Debug.LogFormat("Received dynamic link {0}",
          
 dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString);
 }

 // Display the dynamic link received by the application.
 void OnDynamicLink(object sender, EventArgs args) {
 var dynamicLinkEventArgs = args as ReceivedDynamicLinkEventArgs;
 Debug.LogFormat("Received dynamic link {0}",
          
 dynamicLinkEventArgs.ReceivedDynamicLink.Url.OriginalString);
 }
```

but the recieved link returns our homepage and not 'p'

Again any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason this wasnt working for me so for anyone searching as this has been troubling us for some time.

In the end it was because I was using a shortened link which was occluding the parameters I needed, once I tried using the original long link it worked straight away

So for cleanliness sake, I use a link to our website plus the required param, the site takes the param and inserts it into a preset long dynamic link url and redirects to that link, this gives us a nice tidy url with the benefits of parameters